# how to Split and get data in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I am newbie in ruby.
Now, I have problem about text splitting by ruby programming.

My text is like

```
AA:0.88:320:800|BB:0.82:1040:1330|CC:0.77:1330:1700|DD:0.71:1700:2010|EE:1.00:2070:2390
```

So I need result to   (process until end of text)

```
AA 0.88
BB 0.82
CC 0.77
DD 0.71
EE 1.00
```

How to coding it. Now I can only split by "|".

Best regard.

Comment: Split by "|", then each part split again by ":"

Answer (score 4):

Use [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split):

```
s = 'AA:0.88:320:800|BB:0.82:1040:1330|CC:0.77:1330:1700|DD:0.71:1700:2010|EE:1.00:2070:2390'
s.split('|').each do |substring|
  name, num, * = substring.split(':')
  puts "#{name} #{num}"
end
```

output:

```
AA 0.88
BB 0.82
CC 0.77
DD 0.71
EE 1.00
```

Comment: BTW, warning `unused rest variable` may be suppressed if you simply don’t name the rest: `s1, s2, * = substring.split(':')`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I've got no warning. In which environ do you run the code? BTW, thank you for suggestion. I updated the code according to your comment.

Comment: Some IDEs do *highlight* it.

Comment: You can also use `_` instead of `*` to explicitly state that you want to discard the value. Although it makes no functional difference, I think it is good practice.

Comment: @p11y, Both are not equivalent. Think about this: `_ = 1; a, b, _ = [1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: @falsetru, I see what you mean, but an assignment makes no sense, when all arguments are discarded. However, I may need to rethink this whole thing since `_ = 1` might be really confusing. On the other hand, `* = 1` is really confusing, too :). The usage of underscore I described is just a thing I have seen in a lot of good code, whereas I can only remember the splat `*` being used to actually capture values.

Comment: @p11y, I just wanted to say that `..., _ = ...` has a side effect.

Comment: @falsetru oh, I see! I didn't think that the existence of the `_` variable would change the meaning of the parallel assignment. That's actually one very good reason to use `*`. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

And here, just for reference, is a regexp version:

```
s = 'AA:0.88:320:800|BB:0.82:1040:1330|CC:0.77:1330:1700|DD:0.71:1700:2010|EE:1.00:2070:2390'
p s.scan /(?:\||\A)([^:]+):([^:]+)/
# => [["AA", "0.88"], ["BB", "0.82"], ["CC", "0.77"], ["DD", "0.71"], ["EE", "1.00"]]
```

The code is shorter but much harder to read and debug. Use the other answers before this one!

Edit:

And here is the same regexp with some comments:

```
s.scan %r{
  (?: \| | \A) # Look for start of string (\A) or '|' (\|) but do not include in capture (?:)
  ([^:]+)      # Look for and capture one or more characters that are not ':'
  :            # Look for but do not capture a ':', Not captured as line is not in parenthesis.
  ([^:]+)      # Repeat second line.
}x # x modifies the regexp to allow comments.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'AA:0.88:320:800|BB:0.82:1040:1330|CC:0.77:1330:1700'
s.split('|').map { |item| # produces an array and remaps it
  s1, s2, * = item.split(':')
  puts "#{s1} #{s2}"
  [s1, s2]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub` and 
regex:

```
str = "AA:0.88:320:800|BB:0.82:1040:1330|CC:0.77:1330:1700|" +
      "DD:0.71:1700:2010|EE:1.00:2070:2390"

puts str.gsub(':',' ').scan(/(([A-Z])\2 \d\.\d\d)/).map(&:first)

AA 0.88
BB 0.82
CC 0.77
DD 0.71
EE 1.00
```

These are the steps:

```
s1 = str.gsub(':',' ')
  # => "AA 0.88 320 800|BB 0.82 1040 1330|CC 0.77 1330 1700|
       DD 0.71 1700 2010|EE 1.00 2070 2390" (broken for display)
s2 = s1.scan(/(([A-Z])\2 \d\.\d\d)/)
  # => [["AA 0.88", "A"], ["BB 0.82", "B"], ["CC 0.77", "C"],
        ["DD 0.71", "D"], ["EE 1.00", "E"]] 
s3 = s2.map(&:first)
  # => ["AA 0.88", "BB 0.82", "CC 0.77", "DD 0.71", "EE 1.00"]
```

In the regex, `/(...)/` and `([A-Z])` are the first and second capture groups, respectively. `\2` equals what is captured by the second group, so `` `([A-Z])\2 `` requires that the same two  capital letters appear together (e.g., 'CC').